# Computing probability function of $Y$ in terms of $f_X$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability density function $f_X$, and let $Y = 10/X$.
Compute $f_Y$, the probability density function of $Y$, in terms of $f_X$.

Comment: Hint: determine the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of $Y$ in terms of the cdf of $X$, and then differentiate.

Comment: What I did is as follows
Fy(Y) = P(Y<=y) = P(10/X<=y)
= P(X<=y)(10/Y)
=Fx(10y/Y)
Fy(y) = 10y/Y

fY(y) = FY'(y) = d/dy(10y/yY)

I was unsure of what to do after P(10/x<=y) and my calculations probably do not make much sense

Comment: If X is continuous r.v. $P(Y \leq y)=P(10/y \leq X) = 1- P(X \leq 10/y)=1-F_x(10/y)$ so $f_Y(y)=f_x(10/y)\cdot 10/y^2$